# How to adjust size of the button for android automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to Android i need to implement buttons having the size of background image how can i  implement this?

In sort i want to adjust size of the button according to background image

Comment: What advantage you are going to get if you implement buttons having the size of background image? Will background image get visible then?

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch. This is best practise for Button background images in Android. If this does not meet your requirement I would ask the same question like Paresh Mayani.

Comment: @PareshMayani yeah background image should be visible than after ,i'll change the background image dynamically after that and size of the button should be change accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/image">

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

when you set image on button then it must have set

```
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

when we set it layout_width,layout_height then button automatically re size same as image size so don't worry for that. you can you button like below example.

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:background="@drawable/image"/>
```